#  SENCHA :How to add/remove text fields dynamically by clicking ADD / DELETE buttons in SENCHA touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have implemented a function using Sencha touch.

In that i have designed a view with 2 buttons **ADD, DELETE** in a file in VIEW.

AQnd add corresponding **controllers** for the button in CONTROLLER file

controller works fine for **console out put**

But i need to **add any one form** like textfield or text area of field set, by taping on **ADD** button dynamically

**Delete one form** when tap **DELETE** button dynamically.

**View File:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {
           extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

           config: {
           items: [
                   {
                   xtype: 'button',
                   id: 'addButton',
                   height: 33,
                   left: '',
                   margin: '500px',
                   padding: '',
                   right: '400px',
                   ui: 'confirm-round',
                   width: 100,
                   text: 'Add'
               },

                   {
                   xtype: 'button',
                   id: 'deleteButton',
                   height: 33,
                   margin: '500px',
                   right: '296px',
                    ui: 'decline-round',
                   width: 100,
                   text: 'Delete'
                   }
                   ]
           }});
```

[image]

**Controller file:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        views: [
            'MainPanel'
        ],


    },

    init: function() {
           this.control({

                        '#addButton': {
                        tap: function() {

                         console.log('Add field');

                        }
                        },


                        '#deleteButton': {
                        tap: function() {

                        console.log('Delete field');

                        }
                        },
        });
    },
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like almost exactly what you're trying to do: http://www.swarmonline.com/2011/05/dynamic-sencha-touch-forms-part-3-adding-form-fields-on-the-fly/

However, it's written for Sencha Touch 1.0, so the solution is slightly different for 2.0...

First, place your button in a fieldset:

**View File**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {
       extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

       config: {
           items: [
                {
           xtype: 'fieldset',
                   items: [
                       /** your two button configs here **/
                   ]
                }
       }
 });
```

Now you can access the field set from the button tap handler and add fields. Remember to add your button as an argument to the handler.

```
tap: function(button){
    button.up('fieldset').add({
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'MyField-' + button.up('fieldset').length
    });
}
```

You can also add other options such as `placeholder` to your field config.

EDIT:

Likewise, to remove fields, simply use the remove method instead (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-remove):

```
 button.up('fieldset').remove(button.up('fieldset').items.items[0]); // remove 1st item
```